# Add Basic HTTP Authentication header to AFHttpRequestOperation & download file

Tags: ios, afnetworking

I'm not finding any API in AFHttpRequestOperation where HTTP headers can be added. Looks like AFHttpClient has that support but all the examples appear to be using AFHttpClient for posting data rather than downloading.

How can I add custom Http Header or authentication headers to AFHttpRequestOperation?

Also, is there any way to download data from HTTP server in memory as NSData instead of writing it to a file directly when using AFHttpRequestOperation?

Answer (score 6):

You're correct that there is no direct method in AFHTTPRequestOperation for adding HTTP headers, luckily that was intentional.

The setup of an AFHTTPRequestOperation may seem cumbersome at first but it does make a lot of sense once you've used it.

1. Create a AFHTTPClient. `AFHTTPClient *client = [AFHTTPClient clientWithBaseURL:[NSURL URLWithString:@"http://mysite.com]];`
2. Setup your headers in your AFHTTPClient with the appropriate method:

   `[client setDefaultHeader:@"key" value:@"value"];

   [client setAuthorizationHeaderWithUsername:@"username" password:@"password"];

   [client setAuthorizationHeaderWithToken:@"token"];`
3. Create a NSURLRequest using your AFHTTPClient, this is the key
   `NSURLRequest *request = [client requestWithMethod:@"someMethod" path:@"somePath" parameters:nil];`
4. Create the AFHTTPRequestOperation with your NSURLRequest
   `AFHTTPRequestOperation *operation = [[AFHTTPRequestOperation alloc] initWithRequest:request];`

From there you're set. You can use `- setCompletionBlockWithSuccess:failure:` or you can just use `[operation start]` and do something else. But this should work perfectly with your HTTP headers for whatever you want.