# Making user login with AFNetworking and AFJSONRequestOperation

Tags: jsonp, afnetworking

I am very new in objC, I need implement a simple feature like authenticate user. I read a lot of tutorial but it is too complicated and not focusing on get response from server after post value. Could you please show me what should I do.

The server URL like this: http://server.com/demo/index.php/api/user/login/format/json
and I have to POST param value:

```
array(
"email" => "admin@server.com",
"password" =>"123456"
);
```

What I will get is true or false as json response. How can I make it?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My [answer here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13353718/902968) explains exactly how you need to use `AFNetworking` to do this.